# when I sent transaction, web app redirects to app store on iphone

Tags: iphone, metamask, wallet-connect

I made web app and tried to send transaction using metamask on iphone but it redirects to app store.
It works well on desktop and Android.
I used walletconnect for connecting wallet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/pull/4167

Seems like an existing metamask issue with Deeplinking redirecting to Appstore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).